# Over-percentage while creating PICKLE (Python)

Tags: python, pickle

To the following code happens a strange thing when executed: the percentage which shows completition is going over 100%. The code is running for about 45 minutes by now..

This is the code I adapted to Python 3 after the errors [original one](https://github.com/seeb0h/seeb0h.github.io/blob/master/code-samples/2016-06-07/preprocess.py) gave me.

```
'''
Read and pre-process SD19 characters text file.
Blog post : http://seeb0h.github.io/howto/preprocess-sd19-dataset-for-digits-learning/
Characters in txt file are in 128x128 images with much padded zeros.
It may be suitable for learning to have smaller, deskewed, trimmed, squared ones
Following preprocessing is applied to the dataset:
 - Read glyph (see read_glyph())
 - Moment-based image deskew (see deskew())
 - Trim zeros rows and columns (see trim_padding())
 - Resize image while keeping aspect ratio (see resize_with_constant_ratio())
 - Pad zeros in order to get a square image (see pad_digit())
Extends original code from http://asciirain.com/wordpress/2013/04/08/exploring-sd19-glyph-recognition-with-randomforests/
Usage:
   preprocess_sd19_text.py

'''
#

import os
import re
import sys
import pickle
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

def read_glyph(_line):
    """Extract digit from the text file
    Parameters
    ----------
    _line : string
        current line in SD19 text file
    Returns
    -------
    digit : np.array
        2D digit 128x128
    label : int
        the label
    """
    match = re.search("^(\S+) (\d+)", _line)
    label = match.group(1)
    vector = list(match.group(2))
    vector = [int(x) for x in vector]

    label = ord(label)
    label = str(symbol_map[label]) #changed from int to str

    digit = np.array(vector, 'float32')
    digit = (digit*-1.+1.).reshape(128, 128)

    return digit, label

def deskew(img):
    """Deskew digit
    Parameters
    ----------
    img : np.array
        2D digit array
    Returns
    -------
    dst : Deskewed digit
    """
    m = cv2.moments(img)
    if abs(m['mu02']) < 1e-2:
        return img.copy()
    skew = m['mu11']/m['mu02']
    rot_mat = np.float32([[1, skew, -0.5*max(img.shape[0], img.shape[1])*skew], [0, 1, 0]])
    img = cv2.warpAffine(img, rot_mat, (img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), flags=cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return img


def resize_with_constant_ratio(img, char_dim):
    """Resize image while keeping aspect ratio. Max dim is char_dim
    pad_dim is applied in order to have derivative friendly image
    Parameters
    ----------
    img : np.array
        2D digit array
    char_dim : int
        dst dim
    Returns
    -------
    dst : resized digit
    """
    roi_h = img.shape[0]
    roi_w = img.shape[1]

    max_dim = max(roi_w, roi_h)
    pad_dim = 2
    scale = float(char_dim-pad_dim) / max_dim
    if roi_w >= roi_h:
        new_w = int(char_dim-pad_dim)
        new_h = int(roi_h * scale)
    else:
        new_w = int(roi_w * scale)
        new_h = int(char_dim-pad_dim)

    dst = cv2.resize(img, (new_w, new_h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    return dst

def trim_padding(img):
    """Trim zeros rows and columns
    Parameters
    ----------
    img : np.array
        2D digit array
    Returns
    -------
    dst : trimmed digit
    """
    mask_row = np.all(np.equal(img, 0), axis=1)
    dst = img[~mask_row]

    mask_col = np.all(np.equal(dst, 0), axis=0)
    dst = dst[:, ~mask_col]

    return dst

def pad_digit(img, char_dim):
    """Pad zeros in order to get a square char_dimxchar_dim image
    Parameters
    ----------
    img : np.array
        2D digit array
    char_dim : int
        image dim
    Returns
    -------
    dst : padded digit
    """
    pad_h = char_dim-img.shape[0]
    pad_w = char_dim-img.shape[1]
    pad_h_b = math.floor(pad_h/2)
    pad_h_t = pad_h - pad_h_b
    pad_w_r = math.floor(pad_w/2)
    pad_w_l = pad_w - pad_w_r

    dst = np.hstack(( img, np.zeros((img.shape[0], pad_w_r))))
    dst = np.hstack(( np.zeros((dst.shape[0], pad_w_l)), dst))

    dst = np.vstack(( dst, np.zeros((pad_h_b, dst.shape[1]))))
    dst = np.vstack(( np.zeros((pad_h_t, dst.shape[1])), dst))

    return dst


def print_overwrite(text):
    """Print with overwrite (for progression counter)
    Parameters
    ----------
    text : string
          text to display
    """
    delete = "\b" * (len (text)+1)
    print ("{0}{1}".format(delete, text)),

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (__doc__)

    sd19_filename = "sd19-binary_digits.txt"
    data = open(sd19_filename, "r")
    dataset = []
    symbol_map = dict([(x, chr(x)) for x in list(range(48, 58)) + list(range(65, 91)) + list(range(97, 123))])  #added list() to every range

    current_dir = os.curdir

    num_records = 0
    num_lines = 402953

    char_dim=28
    pickle_name = "SD19_" + str(char_dim) + "x" + str(char_dim) + "_"


    for line in data:
        num_records += 1

        if num_records%20000 == 0:
            with open(os.path.join(current_dir, pickle_name +\
                    str(num_records) + ".pickle"), 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(dataset, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        print_overwrite("num_records : {}/{} - {:5.2f}%"\
            .format(num_records, num_lines, num_records*1./num_lines*100))

        digit, label = read_glyph(line)
        digit_deskewed = deskew(digit)
        digit_trimmed = trim_padding(digit_deskewed)
        digit_resized = resize_with_constant_ratio(digit_trimmed, char_dim)
        digit_padded = pad_digit(digit_resized, char_dim)

        item = []
        item.append((digit_padded*255).astype('uint8'))
        item.append(label)
        dataset.append(item)


    with open(os.path.join(current_dir, pickle_name +\
                str(num_lines) + ".pickle"), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(dataset, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

It is used to create PICKLE from a .txt file containing binary images. For more see [here](http://seeb0h.github.io/howto/preprocess-sd19-dataset-for-digits-learning/).

And my "error"...

[image: files]

By now it is at 135% and last PICKLE file is around 400mb...

Why it happens ? Also, it continue to create files (should have stopped at 400.000 or little more).

Comment: EDIT: it finished at 202,07% with a file dimension of 646mb. Too strange..

Comment: You have `num_lines` hardcoded as 402953 in your code.  That is obviously not the right number for this particular file.

Comment: So, how to make it right ? The code has been just tooked from the source I indicated...Thanks

Comment: You would need to read through the entire file first, to find out how many lines are in it.  Alternatively, you could base your percentage on the number of characters read, as you can determine the total size of the file without actually reading it.

Comment: So the percentage shown in CMD can actually be wrong ?

Comment: Well, yes - if you perform a calculation using a hardcoded number that isn't correct, then OF COURSE you can end up with the wrong results!